# Does Redisson RLocalCachedMap get invalidated with the changes in Redis-Server?

Tags: redis, redisson, clientside-caching

My use case:
I have a single node application(MyApplication) which uses RLocalCachedMap (say testMap)to communicate with redis-server and also cache data locally in aplication.
On the other hand there is another Non java application say anotherApplication(which we have no control of) will update the data in redis-server on same map testMap.
In which case, does RLocalCachedMap in get MyApplication will invalidate the local cache entries ?

If not, how would you suggest to implement Redis Server assisted client side caching (https://redis.io/topics/client-side-caching)?
Is there a way that i can use listen to redis-server invalidation events and keep the local cache in sync with redis-server data (with or without RLocalCachedMap as Its not mandate for use to use RLocalCahedMap). ?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of RLocalCachedMap is to invalidate locally cached entries by default. See the default behavior [here](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/blob/master/redisson/src/main/java/org/redisson/api/LocalCachedMapOptions.java#L183), along with configurable strategies.